# How to show a comment box into your web page using html and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm setting up my static web page, and I want to try to show the user comment, I already write the comment script using html and got no idea how to write the javascript to show the comment under my post, can someone help  me? thanks anyway

```
<section>
                    <form method="post" action="#">
                        <div class="row gtr-50">
                            <div class="col-6 col-12-small">
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="contact-name" placeholder="Name" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6 col-12-small">
                                <input type="text" name="email" id="contact-email" placeholder="Email" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <textarea name="message" id="contact-message" placeholder="Message" rows="4"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <ul class="actions">
                                    <li><input type="submit" class="style1" value="Send" /></li>
                                    <li><input type="reset" class="style2" value="Reset" /></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                    </form>
                </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wait...
You need to add third party comment helper for your static html page.. Because static can not store data.. To store your comment you need a database or Third-party comment app.. If you have no idea about database then just use Third-party  app.

[This link might help you](https://darekkay.com/blog/static-site-comments/)